# Custom data validation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, data-validation

Using the custom data validation rule, is it possible to only allow values that follow the below criteria:

1. Length = 7
2. First 3 digits = "ISO"
3. Digits 4,5 & 6 must be numbers

I currently allow any value and have another column to test this logic, then filter on the TRUEs,

I use the below to test the logic mentioned above:

```
=AND(LEN(Table1[@[ISO ISO LINK]])=7,LEFT(Table1[@[ISO ISO LINK]],3)="ISO",ISNUMBER(IFERROR(MID(Table1[@[ISO ISO LINK]],4,3)+0,"A")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formula like:

```
=AND(LEN(D2)=7,LEFT(D2,3)="ISO",NUMBERVALUE(MID(D2,4,3)+1))
```

[image]

Should do what you want

Comment: Note that if the three digits are all zero, data validation will fail.

Comment: Good point, adding `1` to the number value will fix that problem. See my edited answer